# How to delete a portion of timeline without having the rest of that channel "slip"

Tags: video-editor, vegas-pro

*Sony Platinum Studio V 12*

I want to delete a portion of one channel and have the rest of that channel NOT SLIDE around, i.e., stay sync'd with the OTHER channels.

Note:the Sound Effect clip outlined in red is odd. There is no *Trim Event End* handle.

[image]